# Spring @Transactional annotation is not working for @RabbitListener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-amqp

I have a RabbitMQ handler annotated with `@Transactional` is generating transaction but seems to not join the transaction which throws `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`.

```kotlin
@Component
@RabbitListener(queuesToDeclare = [Queue(name = QUEUE_NAME)], errorHandler = "RabbitErrorHandler")
class RabbitListener(
    private val repository: RepositoryImpl,
) {
    @Transactional
    @RabbitHandler
    fun receive(
        @Payload
        str: String
    ) {
        println("Message Received: $str")
        repository.save(SomeEntity()) // Doing Persist
    }
}
```

TransactionInterceptor TRACE Log

```
[ntContainer#0-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [com.asomethings.listener.RabbitListener.receive]
[ntContainer#0-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [com.asomethings.listener.RabbitListener.receive] after exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

I tried decorating `@Transactional` on repository method which didn't work and also giving `Propagation.MANDATORY` didn't work either.

Only one way it worked was executing `entityManager.joinTransaction()` which I think it is not right.

Used Spring Boot 2.7.1 and Kotlin 1.7.0

Comment: It should work fine. Do you have `@EnableTransactionManagement` on one of your `@Configuration` classes?

Comment: @GaryRussell I don't have `@EnableTransactionManagement` since I use Spring Boot it seems it's automatically enabled in spring boot data jpa

Comment: @GaryRussell It seems JPATransactionManager was replaced by QueryDSL's SQL DatasourceTransactionManager. Which caused `@Transactional` to work incorrectly. Thanks for helping me out!